# Can I put an anchor's href value in its contents automatically, without JS?

Tags: html

For the purpose of rapid coding and reducing tedium, **I want to know if it's possible to auto-generate the contents of an HTML anchor as its `href` value without using JavaScript**. The application I'll be using this in has pages large enough for a JavaScript solution to introduce significant lag.

Example:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="autofill"></a>
```

Is this possible? Is it W3C-compliant? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, to an extent.** You can use the CSS2 `content` property and its `attr` value to get the value of an anchor's `href` attribute. For instance:

```
<style>
.autofill:after {
  content: attr(href);
}
</style>

<a href="http://example.com" class="autofill"></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aA4Em/2/

**This is *not* guaranteed to work cross-browser!** For instance, in the current version of WebKit (Safari, Chrome, Yandex, Rockmelt, many mobile browsers, etc.), the link text is rendered, but it *cannot* be clicked. That said, it works as you might expect in the currently most-used versions of Presto (Opera, soon to be replaced by WebKit), Trident (Internet Explorer), and Gecko (Firefox, Waterfox, etc.).

Mind you I don't know if this is W3C-compliant or not (I don't even know if an empty anchor is W3C-compliant), so my answer is definitely to **use this solution at your own risk**.

### Update

---

As of this edit (2013-04-30), Google's **Chromium** platform's flavor of Webkit (Chrome, Yandex, Rockmelt, many mobile browsers, etc.) and Blink (Currently just Chrome Canary) **now allows users to click anchor pseudo-elements**. Safari, which still runs on Apple's flavor of WebKit, still does not allow this.